# Toggling displaying children using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

When the "Album 1" link is clicked I want to toggle between hiding and showing the photos. However, right now it's not doing anything at all. I tried to debug it in console, but it's not outputting anything useful.

script.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // album click toggle
    $('.album a').click(function() {
        console.log($(this).parent().find(".photos"));
        $(this).parent().find(".photo").hide();
    });
});
```

---

index.html

```
<div class="album">
            <h2><a href="#">Album 1</a></h2>
            <ul class="photos">
                <li>
                    <img src="img/img1.jpg">
                    <span class="info"><span>Image 1</span></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/img2.jpg">
                    <span class="info"><span>Image 2</span></span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="img/img3.jpg">
                    <span class="info"><span>Image 3</span></span>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: There's a huge difference between `.find(".photo")` and the actually correct class `.find(".photos")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your $(this).parent() refer to h2

and is '.photos' not '.photo'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        // album click toggle
        $('.album a').click(function() {
            console.log($(this).parent().parent().find(".photos"));
            $(this).parent().parent().find(".photos").hide();
        });
    });
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            // album click toggle
            $('.album a').click(function() {
                console.log($(this).parents().find(".photos"));
                $(this).parents().find(".photos").hide();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting `.photo` instead of `.photos`.

Beside that you could actually **Toggle** like:

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  // album click toggle
  $('.album a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // Prevent browser scroll to top
    $(this).closest(".album").find(".photos").stop().slideToggle();
  });
  
  
});
```

```css
*{margin:0; box-sizing:border-box;}

.album ul  {display:none; list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; overflow:auto;}
.album li  {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
.album li>*{display:block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="album">
  <h2><a href="#">Album 1</a></h2>
  <ul class="photos">
    <li>
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x50">
      <span class="info"><span>Image 1</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x50">
      <span class="info"><span>Image 2</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x50">
      <span class="info"><span>Image 3</span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="album">
  <h2><a href="#">Album 2</a></h2>
  <ul class="photos">
    <li>
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x50">
      <span class="info"><span>Image 1</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x50">
      <span class="info"><span>Image 2</span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="//placehold.it/64x50">
      <span class="info"><span>Image 3</span></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```